# Not able to create a index with specific shard numbers in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Am working on ES to create some new index in ES by limiting the shard number using below command

```
curl  -XPUT localhost:9200/es_test_index  '{ "settings : { "number_of_shards" ; 2 } }'
```

but there is small  issue the index is getting created but no with shard as 2 instead with the default shard count 5.  Can anyone please tell  me how to change this.

AM working on ES 5.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo you need to use `:` instead of `;` plus you're missing the `-d` switch , try like this instead:

```
curl  -XPUT localhost:9200/es_test_index -d '{ "settings : { "number_of_shards": 2 } }'
                                          ^                                  ^
                                          |                                  |
                                       add this                           fix this
```